# How do I negate an entire Solr query in the Spring framework which contains a join clause

Tags: java, spring, join, solr

I have the following query:

```
{!join from=conceptNcid to=ncid fromIndex=hdd_rel_tst}relationshipNcid:364
```

which I implemented in Spring:

```
SimpleQuery search = new SimpleQuery(new SimpleStringCriteria("*:*"), pageable);

Criteria criteria = new Criteria("relationshipNcid").is("364");

SimpleFilterQuery fq = new SimpleFilterQuery(criteria);

fq.setJoin(Join.from("conceptNcid").fromIndex("hdd_rel_tst").to("ncid"));

search.addFilterQuery(fq);

Page<T> results = solrTemplate.queryForPage(search, myclass);
```

This query works great.  However, when I attempt to negate the query:

```
-{!join from=conceptNcid to=ncid fromIndex=hdd_rel_tst}relationshipNcid:364
```

with this code:

```
SimpleQuery search = new SimpleQuery(new SimpleStringCriteria("*:*"), pageable);

Criteria criteria = new Criteria("relationshipNcid").is("364").not();

SimpleFilterQuery fq = new SimpleFilterQuery(criteria);

fq.setJoin(Join.from("conceptNcid").fromIndex("hdd_rel_tst").to("ncid"));

search.addFilterQuery(fq);

Page<T> results = solrTemplate.queryForPage(search, myclass);
```

it does not work.  Notice where I put the 'not()' on the second line.  I know this is the wrong place, but I can't see how to negate the entire query in the java code.  Any ideas?

Comment: Great question, I am also looking for this answer. Did you get to a working solution?